# Mac OS install drive not being recognized by computer

Tags: usb, install, dual-boot, bootable-disk

I recently installed Mac OS 10.10 (Yosemite) onto an external USB drive. It has been working fine for the past few days. When I need to switch OS installs, I shut down the computer and then pull out the drive. However I think I just pulled out the drive a little too early, while it was still being written to, and now the drive is not being recognized at all by the computer. I get the following message.

[image]

Is there any way I can still save the drive without losing all my work on it? Thanks.

Comment: If you have anything not that drive that you really need to recover **do not initialize it** and I'd use [DiskWarrior](http://www.alsoft.com/diskwarrior/index.html) to attempt recovery.  I'd also make a binary backup if the USB drive using `dd` before doing anything.

Answer (score 2):

You could plug it in, hit "Ignore", open "Disk Utility", and attempt to "Repair" the disk. Otherwise, try to initialize the disk and copy the folder contents.

**P.S.** Just as a side note, I would recommend using an external hard drive(SSD or HDD) to run OS X, since it would operate a little faster.

Comment: your PS… you mean internal?

Comment: @Tetsujin No, I mean the one he has Yosemite installed on. The corrupt one.

Comment: What do you mean be "initialize the disk and copy the folder contents"? Right now i care more about the files and would like to safely get them back rather then trying to fix the actual OS on the drive.

Comment: Additionally, I specifically got a high end USB- 3 with read speeds of 250 MBs and the OS runs pretty fast. Not as fast as my internal SSD, but only slightly noticeably different.

Comment: Ok, thats what I expected. It's just that when I tried it, it failed miserably. But that's just because I have an old Mac.

Comment: Could you explain how to copy the files over?

Comment: Ok. I assume that you tried Disk Utility. Click "Ignore". Open Disk Utility. Mount the disk. Then, it should appear in finder. From there you should be able to copy over the entire folder structure. If not, you may need to [show all hidden files](http://ianlunn.co.uk/articles/quickly-showhide-hidden-files-mac-os-x-mavericks/) and then copy it to some directory. Then use Disk Utility to wipe it and reinstall OS X. Then go back into your computer and copy the folders over, but **do not** replace any files. I do not believe you can "Time Machine" it

Comment: The mount option is not available. Only the eject option is.

Comment: Well in that case, you probably want to restore it and try to retrieve the data using a recovery software(look at [this](http://superuser.com/questions/89579/how-do-i-recover-files-from-an-usb-flash-drive) post on superuser). If you hit "Erase", it most likely will error out, so go to the partition manager, select 1 partition, and reformat it as Mac OS Extended. Then try to recover all files. In the future, just remember it is **very** important to keep your flash drive in good health, including waiting until you know it's safe to remove.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Thanks for the input.

Comment: No problem. I'm sorry you couldn't recover the data.